# How could I generate a PWM signal from a control voltage

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm

I want to use a control voltage to generate a PWM signal that will drive a DC motor. I can't use a potentiometer with a 555 timer as I have to control it from National Instruments LabView software with a voltage output.

Comment: Welcome to electronics.stackexchange. Is this homework? Can you edit your question to show a conceptual block-diagram of what you want to achieve?

Comment: If you have to control it from software, forget the control voltage and generate PWM directly.

Comment: Use a micro-controller.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a suitable voltage output that you can control you can hook that up to a 555 instead of using a potentiometer.

[image]

If you read the 555 data sheet, you can find out what is required on the modulation input.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a proof of concept for an ATtiny13 microcontroller once. The code can be found [here](http://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=adc2pwm13;a=summary).

Basically what the program does is read the top eight bits of the ADC (pin 3) and convert that to a PWM signal (pin 6).  All you need is a microcontroller (ATtiny13 or similar AVR) a 5V power supply, a capacitor to decouple the power supply and a programmer... For the programmer I personally use a spare Arduino, which brings me to the other option: Use a small Arduino.

Comment: What, you have something against *big* Arduinos? :-)

Comment: Not at all @AnindoGhosh, but it isn't necessary to spend more money than necessary, hence my ATtiny proposal.

Comment: Thanx jippie i am very much comfortable with your suggestion regarding ATtiny 13.

Comment: @ghosh sir i have done it with arduino but i want some cheap method for it

Comment: @vishantKumar define "cheap"